# Using asyncio, what is the easiest way to wait for all results and additionally get them back?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a long running function that gets called several times by a `for` loop with different parameters.

I want to evaluate the `asyncio` library to easily increase the speed of that function.

The function delivers back a certain value that should be stored on the level of the `for` loop in a list `resultList`.

I found some code snippets already that seem to fulfill my requirement of being 'easy to implement' (I just have to add the `@background` decorator), but I am missing two functionalities:

1. how to wait on the level of the `for` loop until all executions of the function are performed?
2. how to collect the results of the function call on the level of the `for` loop?

How would I have to extend this code snippet?

```
import asyncio
import time

def background(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, f, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped

@background
def your_function(argument):
    time.sleep(5)
    myReturn = 'function finished for ' + str(argument)
    print(myReturn)
    return  myReturn


if __name__ == '__main__':
    resultList = []

    for i in range(10):
        your_function(i)
        # resultList.append() 


    # loop = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete()

    print('this should only be printed once all calls to your_function() are finished')
    print("resultList=", resultList) # should contain a list of entries with 'function finished for x'
```

Comment: Is your process I/O limited? Otherwise `asyncio` will not help at all since the GIL is still active, and only one thread can process Python code concurrently. The code snippet does not look like it will benefit from that at all. I know this does not answer the question, but I'd like to avoid you going down an unneccessary path.

Comment: Thanks for making aware of this topic. My function is I/O limited, yes.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues I am seeing with the code you shared. Note: my answer is based on your comment to Jan where you mention that your function is I/O limited.

1. Don't use `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor()`, use `asyncio.run()`
   at your entry point and keep your methods async all the way, if you can. (https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run)
2. You are using `time.sleep()`. This is a synchronous version of sleep which will not simulate asyncio. Use `asyncio.sleep()` instead.
3. Note that `run_in_executor` returns a future object, which you want to `await`. Since you are running your code in a synchronous function this is more involved than running it all from an async function.

Now, by looking at the code you shared, there's no reason to convert its stack to `asyncio`. If there are other external limitation, or this is just a snippet of a larger program, the solution below might be a bit different. Otherwise the solution below is straightforward.

```
import asyncio

async def your_function(argument):
    await asyncio.sleep(5)  # note the await here (compared to time.sleep())
    my_return = f"function finished for {argument}"
    print(my_return)
    return my_return


async def async_main():
    result_list = await asyncio.gather(*(range(10)))  # gather will run it all concurrently
    print("this should only be printed once all calls to your_function() are finished")
    print(f"result_list={result_list}", result_list) # should contain a list of entries with 'function finished for x'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(async_main())
```